# What are Harry Potter's Children?

Tags: harry-potter

Harry is a half-blood and Ginny is a pure-blood, so what does that make his children?
I've been told it means they are pure-bloods but I can't be sure. What do you think?

Comment: 3/4 blood would be the correct racial term - which is still less than pure blood in any case.

Answer (score 13):

To quote Hagrid:

> "See the thing is, Harry, there's some wizards, like the Malfoy family,
>   who think they're better than everyone else because they're what
>   people call 'pure blood' .... And it's codswallop to boot. 'Dirty
>   blood'! Why there isn't a wizard alive today that's not half-blood or
>   less."

So the terms pure blood and half blood are mostly terms used by people who believe in the validity of these false monikers. And since Harry and the rest of the Weasley's never did subscribe to these ideas then it'd be safe to say "neither".

Comment: Certainly Harry and Ginny don't/wouldn't care, but it's still a valid question.

Comment: @MeatTrademark - It's obvious from Hagrid's comment that they are simply labels used only by certain people. And that they're false labels as well, since there are *no* pure blooded wizards anymore.

Comment: I understand your point, but just ignoring the question is *no fun*. The question does say "what do you think?" So I threw in my 2 cents for whatever it's worth. Besides, there is no "real" answer unless pure-blood is defined with strict parameters on generational drift from half-blood.

Answer (score 5):

Since they are both magical, the children should be pure-blood. Doesn't one parent need to be a muggle for a half-blood and both to be a "Mudblood"? (Sorry for dropping the M-bomb there...)

Lily was [mugggle-born](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Half-blood). He is a half-blood (or what would be more accurately described as 3/4-blood but the pure-blood haters gotta hate), therefore Harry and Ginny would *technically* have [half-bloods because of his mother](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Pure-blood). It depends on how many generation you use to define purity.

It should be noted that the first site referenced above states:

> Harry Potter — pure-blood father, Muggle-born mother

then goes on to list the children as

> Two magical parents, known Muggle ancestry
>
> - Albus Severus Potter — half-blood father, pure-blood mother
> - James Sirius Potter — half-blood father, pure-blood mother
> - Lily Luna Potter — half-blood father, pure-blood mother

Sorry the answer is so messy, but the case could be made for either answer. If your only criteria is neither parent being a Muggle, then yes they're pure. If you need to wait generations or distort your family tree / hide your ancestry (as the "accepted" pure-bloods like the Blacks or the Malfoys almost certainly did), then no, they're not pure-blood.

Comment: That's the longest wishy-washy answer I've ever given, and I apologize, but I assure you I started off strongly in favor of them being pure-blood and got muddled down by the "facts," if you could call them that. Best intentions... meh. I vote pure.

Comment: FYI: Harry potter Wikia isn't canon - sometimes it's correct but not always.

Answer (score 4):

As I answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10029/976), JKR modeled the whole idea of blood purity on Nazi analogy.

As such, the Nazist [definitions apply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_Jew?#Nazism):

> In Germany itself, the Ahnenpass and Nuremberg Laws classified people as Jews if they descended from three or four Jewish grandparents. A person with one or two Jewish grandparents was a Mischling, a crossbreed, of "mixed blood".

As far as Harry's children, they were "polluted" blood by those same ideas, but not "mixed blod". [JKR herself said](http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=58):

> **A single Jewish grandparent 'polluted' the blood,** according to their propaganda.

Comment: although I upvoted other answers, this is the one I would most likely accept if I were the asker. It seems the most authoritative since you explain how JKR based her notion of blood purity. So wait, what did "polluted" blood mean? Was it only a label or did it affect the definition for future descendants?
I almost feel dirty/"polluted" asking so many questions about their bigotry, but those who do not learn from history...

Answer (score 2):

From the 'pureblood' view, they would be half-blood, since they have muggle ancestry.  Pureblood is defined as never having mixed with muggles (if you ask most purebloods), or not having any knowledge of muggle ancestry (if you ask everyone else).