# Is there a "first" pureblood in the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: harry-potter

I was reading the question and answers found [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10000/what-percentage-makes-someone-a-half-blood) and I realized something. Distinction between half-bloods and pure-bloods were done using Third Reich rules for Jews. Well in order for magic to exist a "first" Wizard (or witch) should exist. The specific first was muggle born. Given that the first was alone his/her children would be half bloods. If he/she was not alone (let's say another one was created from another family) their children were both descendants of muggle borns.

So in theory all magicians in the magic world are descendants of muggle borns. Unless In the whole harry potter universe exists a "creation/evolution" theory in which the first wizard/witch descended from a different kind of species (or created by god alongside adam and eve even though I do not accept the creationists theory IRL, I would accept it in mythology).

Is there a canon answer to this? Are all Wizards descendants of Muggle borns?

Comment: or could the first humans have been wizards, and non magical children where born from them as well as magical children.

Comment: @phantom42 not exactly. This questions how it started. I am questioning the pureness of the blood since it all leads to a Muggle ancestor

Comment: there is no canon answer to this however, this will all be speculation, unless rowling recently decided to say X was the first wizard and had X Y parents.

Comment: @Himarm The lack of a canon answer [is not grounds to close a question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/should-all-questions-without-explicit-canon-answers-be-closed).

Comment: Yes indeed. I am not requesting a canon answer specifically.

Comment: Why assume a "first wizard" when you don't assume a "first human" (aka Adam)?

Comment: @kutschkem In mythology it does not matter. I accept the first human in mythology. In mythology I could even accept humans only use 10% of their brain if it was not so much overused.

Comment: the answer to this will have to be all opinion based as theres no clues, hints, nothing at all about this though, and opinion based questions are grounds, however if others feel differently thats their opinion :P. it is an interesting question, however i see no way to logically present a real answer that someone else cannon simply say, hrm sounds cool, BUT I THINK ...

Comment: @Himarm yes but doesn't this apply to all non canon answers? Many questions here have non canon answers that are more or less opinion based but given that they have canon arguments backing them up then I suppose it's ok

Comment: i was saying i dont think that anything from the cannon can be used to back anything up, but since others feel this can be answered ill backout and see where it goes.

Comment: @Himarm Oh I misunderstood you. We'll see how it goes

Comment: Yes, the answer is opinion based. No, this doesn't make the question in ANY way offtopic. Go read "Good subjective bad subjective" please. yes, this question is IMHO a full duplicate of linked one.

Comment: I still entertain a pet theory that wizards are part-elf, this of course happened before elves were subjugated.

Comment: @Himarm I love that concept! Would that mean Muggles are just descended from Squibs? It would actually explain Muggleborns nicely.